# Angularjs directive change color of input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs and am pretty new, I need a directive that depending upon a condition it will change the background color of the input box that has the directive attribute. How do I refeence the calling element to change it's background.

Comment: use [ng-class directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass), lets you set a css class depending on some condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `ng-style`, anyway, if you really need it wrapped in a directive I've made it for you in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xnw61bjFSgfPGA6wcPCE?p=preview)

It'll update as soon as the input changes.

What I'm doing there is watching the color changing and set it to an `ng-style`within the directive and transcluding it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how it would look like using the ng-class:
[View Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LJu2F/)

```
<div ng-app>
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-class="{ error: faulty }"  size="30"/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="faulty"/> check me
</form>
```

```
.error { 
    background-color:red; 
    border:2px solid blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below plunk for the example.

I created directive inputBox to do this

```
<input-Box is-maximized="isMaximized" />
```

The directive is

```
<input type="input" ng-class="{mini: (isMaximized == 1), box: (isMaximized == 0)}" />
```

Used ng-class and changed the color based on the condition. if isMaximized is set to 1 in the parent controller it will apply mini class and if it is set to 0 it will apply box class.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ELi3XHk5xWaKMP4MCL2F?p=preview